# How to make rails reload only yield part?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a fixed header for every page on my rails app. Is there any way that when I click every link_to to whatever source only refresh the yield part?

```
<html>
  <body>
  <%= render 'layouts/header' %>
<div class="row">
 <div>
   <%= yield %>
 </div>
</div>
```

The current code make each link refresh whole page including the header

Comment: yes, have a look at rails ujs https://guides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html

Comment: Sounds like you wanna do some ajax goodness. I'd encourage you to check out a front-end framework like Vue or maybe Ember, and then think about the browser-request NPM package. https://www.npmjs.com/package/browser-request

Comment: flagged because you need to read ajax and page chaching (too broad)

Comment: What do you want to achieve by only updating parts of the page? Do you aim for faster page loads? Is it worth it to have more complex code and fighting Rails conventions?